# Join in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Requirement: Need to figure out what LoginIDs have `Default` set to `1` but not `0`. Rule is, all LoginIDs can have `Default` as `0` or `1` but there must be at least one record with `0` for a given `LoginID`.

Table as below:

```
LoginID Default
A       0
A       1
A       1
B       1
B       1
B       1
B       1
C       0
D       0
D       1
E       0
E       1
E       1
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more or add sample output ?

Comment: I don't think you need a JOIN for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be looking for something easy like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LoginID
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE Default = 1
   AND LoginID NOT IN ( SELECT LoginID FROM yourtable WHERE Default = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the MINUS operator.

```
select loginID from your_table where default = 1
minus
select loginID from your_table where default = 0
```

This produces the set of login IDs which have a `default` of `1` but no `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to approach this type of problem using `group by` and `having`:

```
select loginID
from t
group by loginId
having min(default) = 1;
```